# Using methods from another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, arraylist

I have 3 classes:

NewCarListTester - Creates 5 new car objects (Hard coded), Tests methods of other classes.

NewCarList - Contains an ArrayList of cars. Cars are passed into an "add" method and then added to the ArrayList.

NewCar - Constructs New Car, calculates price and contains the toString print out method.

There are 4 methods in "NewCarList." Add, Display, Select, Drop.

The "display" method must use the toString method from "NewCar." The "Select" method must use the "getFinalPrice" method from "NewCar."

How exactly can I access these methods from within the "NewCarList" class? New cars were already created in the tester and added into the arraylist. So it wouldnt make sense to create another NewCar object right?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `NewCar` implements some interface, but even if it doesn't as long as `NewCarList` takes a reference to a `NewCar` then it can call any of the public methods. And `toString` as well as `getFinalPrice` should be public.